# Type composition in dart

Tags: dart

In some class I need to repeat over the over some complex types. Like:

`List<Something<String>>`

Is it possible to compose this type in `Dart` so I wont have to keep re declaring it over and over?

Like in `Go`:

`var whatever []String`

I tried to create class that extend this type:

```
class WhateverList extends List<Something<String>> {}
```

But it complained about `Missing concrete implementation`. I though about using the `decorator pattern` but that will require to map all the methods. Seems a bit over kill.

Is there a way to compose new types in an elegant short syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently not, but there are plans to add type aliases to Dart.

- https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/65
- https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/115

Comment: According to Issue 115 it looks like they have already decided and are already implementing if I interpret that correctly.